# Regular Expression and .htaccess: redirect /cat1/cat2/ → /cat2/

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I'm trying this regex but there are a few problems.. /tag/ shouldn't be stripped /page/2 neither and also

```
/.*?(/[^/]+/)([^/]*)(/feed)?$
```

```
/.*? → match / followed by anything 
(/[^/]+/) → match the last category
([^/]*) → match the name of the file
(/feed)? → match the /feed if it's there
$
```

URLs:

```
http://www.regexbuddy.com/prova/prova1/index.html
http://www.regexbuddy.com/index.html?source=library
https://www.superinformati.com/medicina-e-salute/diete/feed
https://www.superinformati.com/medicina-e-salute/estetica-cosmesi/calvizie/feed
https://www.superinformati.com/medicina-e-salute/denti/feed
https://www.superinformati.com/bellezza/capelli/feed
https://www.superinformati.com/hi-tech/schermi-amoled-costo-inferiori-agli-lcd.htm/page/20
https://www.superinformati.com/soldi-successo/consumatori/page/2
https://www.superinformati.com/medicina-e-salute/disabilita/feed
https://www.superinformati.com/medicina-e-salute/emorroidi/feed
https://www.superinformati.com/medicina-e-salute/anticoncezionali
https://www.superinformati.com/category/bellezza/tatuaggi
https://www.superinformati.com/bellezza/tatuaggi/feed
https://www.superinformati.com/category/medicina-e-salute/dimagrire
https://www.superinformati.com/medicina-e-salute/farmaci-istruzioni/feed
https://www.superinformati.com/bellezza/cellulite/feed
https://www.superinformati.com/medicina-e-salute/occhi/feed
https://www.superinformati.com/bellezza/capelli
https://www.superinformati.com/medicina-e-salute/estetica-cosmesi/chirurgia-estetica
https://www.superinformati.com/tag/high-tech/feed
https://www.superinformati.com/category/medicina-e-salute/maternita
https://www.superinformati.com/tag/antiossidanti
https://www.superinformati.com/psicologia/la-polemica-porta-vantaggi.htm
https://www.superinformati.com/universita/come-scrivere-un-cv-da-inviare-allestero.htm
https://www.superinformati.com/soldi/consumatori/
https://www.superinformati.com/bellezza/tatuaggi
https://www.superinformati.com/medicina-e-salute/estetica-cosmesi
https://www.superinformati.com/medicina-e-salute/farmaci-istruzioni
https://www.superinformati.com/medicina-e-salute/occhi
https://www.superinformati.com/medicina-e-salute/diete
https://www.superinformati.com/dimagrire/integratori
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*/tag/.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*/page/2.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*/[^/]+/[^/]+/feed$
RewriteRule  ^(.*)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.*)$  $1/$3/$4  [QSA]
```

---

This is an example, you should adjust the regex pattern conditions accordingly.